# Partial validations with rails wizard form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

I would like to validate some fields according to tab in the url params

```
class Web < ApplicationRecord
  validate :validate_website, if: -> {params[:tab] == 'address'}

private

  def validate_website
    regexp = %r{\A(http://www\.|https://www\.|http://|https://)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(/.*)?\z}
    if website.present? && !website.match(regexp)
      errors.add :website, "Error"
    end
  end
```

I also tried :

```
  validate :validate_website, if: :tab_address

  def tab_address
    params[:tab] == "address"
  end
```

But no validation works

Comment: Does the model even receive the params like that?  Why not just use a `before_save` method to check and validate?  Have you tried anything like that?

Comment: They are not the params for the model, but for the  wizard steps. Like : account, address, localisation, pictures...

Comment: oh my bad, I misunderstood.

Comment: how did you pass the `params` from controller to the `Web` model ?

Comment: Like another model ;)

if @web.update(web_params)
... end

and web_params :
    params.require(:web).permit(... :website)

Comment: i think there's no such `params` in your model

Comment: Soory,  I misunderstood... theses params are in the urls, like web/edit?tab=account